Why query paramater / URI exclusion not works in "chunk upload"
We have configured Cloud Armor to block sqli-v33-stable/xss-v33-stable/rce-v33-stable, etc., with a priority of 900. Under normal URL access, false positives do not occur. However, our application includes a “chunk upload” feature, and when users upload script files, they are inevitably detected. We want to bypass this detection.
The payload during upload looks like this:
Form data
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrf_token"

1e1169f40f***************************************************8
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_path"

Dummy.jsx
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_modified"

1695346131
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkNumber"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkSize"

10485760
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowCurrentChunkSize"

14154
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalSize"

14154
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowIdentifier"

14154-Dummy.jsx-1713150063454
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowFilename"

Dummy.jsx
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowRelativePath"

Dummy.jsx
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalChunks"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryATPYsXVvR1C2XoQo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Dummy.jsx"
Content-Type: text/plain

..... File Content ....
snip

We’ve tried setting these exclusions, but they don’t seem to work as expected. Any advice would be appreciated.
--request-query-param-to-exclude="op=EQUALS,val=file"
--request-uri-to-exclude="op=STARTS_WITH,val=/task_file/save_with_chunk"
I tried both exclusions setting by Google console web UI and exclusions setting by gcloud command.
Waited about 1hr after setting.
